# How can I use ImageCrop on a results from Grid?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I have this figure produced using `Plot` and `Grid`

```
 fig = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {300, 200}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 14}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  ImagePadding -> 80];  

dfr = Grid[{{fig, fig}, {fig, fig}}, Spacings -> {-12, -12}, 
  Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Now this figure can be exported as pdf but there are extra  white spaces coming from ImagePadding. How can I remove the white space efficiently from the final figure?

Comment: This? `dfr = Grid[{{fig, fig}, {fig, fig}} /. (ImagePadding -> 80) -> ImagePadding -> Automatic, Frame -> False]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Well, the point is that I want to keep the four panels aligned as in the figure above, what you suggested destroys the alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the frame and tick labels are the same for each grid element, you can pre-process the input to specify different option values for `FrameLabel`, `FrameTicks` and `ImagePadding` for border and internal elements:

```
ClearAll[processGrid]
processGrid[padding_: {{Scaled[.05], Scaled[.0025]}, {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.0025]}}, 
  flabel_: {"x", "y"}, fticks_: {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}] = 
  Module[{dims = Dimensions @ #, p = padding[[1, 2]], 
       sft = Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, 
    MapIndexed[Switch[#2, 
       {dims[[1]], 1},  Show[#, FrameTicks -> fticks, ImagePadding -> padding, 
        FrameLabel -> flabel], 
       {_, 1}, Show[#, FrameTicks -> ReplacePart[fticks, {2, 1} -> sft], 
        FrameLabel -> ReplacePart[flabel, {1} -> None], 
        ImagePadding -> ReplacePart[padding, {2, 1} -> p]],
       {dims[[1]], _}, Show[#, FrameTicks -> ReplacePart[fticks, {1, 1} -> sft], 
        FrameLabel -> ReplacePart[flabel, {2} -> None], 
        ImagePadding -> ReplacePart[padding, {1, 1} -> p]], 
       {_, _}, Show[#, FrameTicks -> sft, FrameLabel -> None, 
        ImagePadding -> p]] &, #, {2}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
fig1 = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {300, 200}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 14}, PlotStyle -> Red];

grid = ArrayReshape[{fig1}, {2, 2}, "Fixed"];

Grid[processGrid[][grid], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[processGrid[][ArrayReshape[{fig1}, {3, 2}, "Fixed"]], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

You can specify padding in printer points:

```
Grid[processGrid[{{60, 10}, {60, 10}}][
  ArrayReshape[{fig1}, {2, 2}, "Fixed"]], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) (requires Mathematica 11.3 or higher), which was designed for exactly this purpose:

```
fig = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {300, 200}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 14}, PlotStyle -> Red]

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {{fig, fig}, {fig, fig}},
 Spacings -> 20,
 "ShowFrameLabels" -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Note that I have removed the `ImagePadding->80` setting from `fig`, as it is not necessary (if you want to keep it, you could also set a custom `ImagePadding` as `PlotGrid` option instead). Also note how the labels are automatically hidden where necessary (this is controlled by the `"ShowFrameLabels"` option).

Alternatively, you can use `GraphicsGrid` in version 12.0 or higher to get similar results, although with a bit more manual work required.

Comment: I got this error: Function::slota: Named Slot x in Association[ImagePadding->Abs[#is-#pr],ImageSize->Abs[Apply[Subtract,#is,{1}]],PlotRangeSize->Abs[Apply[Subtract,#pr,{1}]],PlotRange->{#x,#y}]& cannot be filled from <|pr->{{74.5,429.},{229.593,10.5}},is->{{74.,434.},{231.093,10.}}|>. On M.12.0.0?

Comment: @HD2006 Are you using a non-standard Evaluator for the notebook (in the Evaluation > Notebook's kernel)? The current version is unfortunately broken if you use anything other than the default (which should be "Local", you can create a new notebook and see what the default is for you by checking which evaluator is set there)